# Extent of Sandboxing Constraints In Google Chrome for Packaged Apps

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, sandbox

I hope the following question is specific enough.  The short, core version is: **Can a Google Chrome packaged app ever write a file to a user-selected folder?**  But more details about what I'd like to do follow:

I want to create a Google Chrome packaged app, but this app would need to be able to write to a folder of the user's selection.  At first I thought this wasn't possible, but then I found that it is possible to *read* all the files from an arbitrary folder of the user's selection and I was left unsure.  Is there any way to write to it as well?  Further, the (obfuscated) path to the selected folder needs to be retained across sessions so that the user does not need to reselect it every time they run the app.  Is that possible, or is file access of this sort temporary/session-specific?

The more vague rider to my main question: If either of the above is flat out impossible due to sandboxing, is there any other way for one to write an HTML5/JS standalone app that doesn't have these restrictions.  I thought about Metro, but I'd really prefer it to be cross-platform (and ideally webkit based).

Comment: I'm curious if you solved this?  I have the same question.